# Revoking Docusign OAuth Tokens for normal docsign accounts

Tags: docusignapi

I am posting this here, as Docusign has requested all docusign api questions be placed on StackOverflow:

[REFERENCE](http://community.docusign.com/t5/DevZone-has-Moved-Please-post-on-StackOverflow-com-with-tag/Use-StackOverflow-com-with-tag-DocuSignAPI/m-p/23901#M1)

I have been working on a Docusign application that uses their OAuth flow. In order to test this, I have been using my free account (www.docusign.com) to get access tokens from the application I created on my developer account (demo.docusign.net).

The integrator key I am using is live.

In the process of my testing, I have obtained an access token 10 times using the free account. I did not keep track of those tokens as it states that they can be revoked in the web console. [Docusign Reference](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/OAuth2/Revoking%20Tokens.htm)

However, there is no such section in the www.docusign.com account. All it shows is 5 other accounts that I can connect to.

I now have lost all 10 of those tokens, and the response from the service tells me that I reached the maximum number of access tokens.

Now here's the interesting part, if I use my developer account credentials to authenticate to my application, I can see the access tokens that are active, with the option to revoke.

I know that there is a revoke token endpoint, but you need to know the token in order to use it.

How can I revoke these 10 tokens as I no longer know what they are (due to testing), and there is no interface to revoke them on www.docusign.com? Essentially, this account is now locked out of my application.

*I cannot add screenshots to this post as I do not have high enough reputation*

Comment: This sounds like an issue/question for DocuSign Support.  I suggest you contact them, if you haven't already done so.

Comment: @KimBrandl, I completely agree with you. They are the ones who request that all docusign api questions be asked here. I have added a source to my question.

Comment: I agree that this is the appropriate forum for API questions -- but this isn't an API question, since using the API to revoke a token requires that you know the token -- which you don't. Without knowing the token(s), there's no way for you to solve this using the API.  The only way you're going to resolve this issue is with the help of DocuSign Support -- i.e., if you're not seeing the "Connected Apps" (Revoke token) UI within the DocuSign web console, then perhaps there's a way for DocuSign Support to enable that functionality for your account. I'd pursue that route, if I were you.

Comment: Did you try the same using old docusign flow? Revoking tokens is not available in new flow.